# Set Variables Dynamically

Tags: powershell, variables, dynamic

What I'm trying to do is something similar to this:

```
$Range = 1..4

foreach ($Entry in $Range) {
    $Button$Entry = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button$Entry.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size("200","100")
    $Button$Entry.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size("200","100")
    $Button$Entry.Text = "Test $Entry"
}
```

However, I expect this to be something along the lines of the below, I just cant figure out how to add `.Location`, `.Size` and `.Text`.

```
$Range = 1..4

foreach ($Entry in $Range) {
    New-Variable -Name $Button$Entry -Value New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array instead:

```
$Buttons = foreach ($Entry in 1..4)
{
  $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size("200","100")
  $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size("200","100")
  $Button.text = "Test $Entry"
  $Button
}
```

and then refer to the entries by their value - 1:

```
# Button with text "Test 3"
$Buttons[2]
```

Comment: Thanks for such a speedy answer, thats exactly what i was after :).